# Unable to Assign an Incident in workflow- CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

We have used the case Entity, there is default user that is used to assign a case on new creation or reactivation.

We have a workflow created for Case Reactivation, so whenever a case is reopen it is assigned to the default system user. It was working fine till September 20, but now when you give the survey after case resolution and then try to reactivate it it throws error in workflow. It works fine when you try to reactivate without giving the survey.

Error:

```
The real-time workflow named "Case is Resolved/Reopened" failed with the error "Principal user (Id, type=8, roleCount=1, privilegeCount=619, accessMode=0), is missing prvReadmsfp_questionresponse privilege (Id) on OTC=10247 for entity 'msfp_questionresponse'.
```

The System user has the role assigned as of salesperson, giving permission for this entity to salesperson does solve the issue, but the salesperson role is being used by many others to whom permission for this entity can't be given.
Can anyone tell us why this started causing issue after a particular time. Was there any updates from Microsoft Forms Pro for this entity?

Answer (score 0):

Its very possible there have been updates from MS.  You can review the solution history in make.powerplatorm.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/solution-history

Look for the forms pro solution and check the solution history.

Is the "Default" user an actual person that logs in?  Or a Service account that is only used for automation/workflows?

In any case, I'd suggest creating an add-on or feature role called something like "Question Response Reader" that only has the read permission for that entity.  You can then add that role to the default user, and any other users that need to read that entity.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Microsoft changed something in the background especially w.r.t security of forms Response entity `msfp_questionresponse`.

You easily solution is to give proper security rights to user who is ruining your workflow.

If it is run by the owner of the workflow then that user, if workflow runs under the context of user then that user should have read rights for entity  `msfp_questionresponse`